# Search with field priority in array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects like this:

```
var array = [
{ 
  name: "John",
  surname: "Doe",
  title: "mister"
},
{ 
  name: "Jane",
  surname: "Smith",
  title: "miss"
},
{ 
  name: "Doe",
  surname: "Mustermann",
  title: "mister"
}
]
```

I want to implement a search term through this that will look through multiple properties while sorting them with property priority.

**Example:** If search term would be `Doe`, I would like to get this output:

```
[
{ 
  name: "Doe",
  surname: "Mustermann",
  title: "mister"
},
{ 
  name: "John",
  surname: "Doe",
  title: "mister"
}
]
```

`name` property has higher priority than `surname`, that's why hit on name object would go on top.

Filter function only filters through array, but I also would need to move objects up based if search term hit specific field that has higher priority.

I tried implementing this with combination of `filter` and `sort`, but unfortunately this was a failure due to both searching through multiple fields in objects, with moving some objects on top depending on which property search was found.

Comment: Please give a [mre]

Comment: Do it in 2 steps. First Use `filter()` to search for all matches, then `sort()` to order the results by priority.

Comment: Sounds like you want to do SQL type querying on JavaScript objects, like "select x from y order by z". You might want to check out this GitHub project (FYI I've never used it): https://github.com/jamesmh/JavaScript-Sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a list of fields, ordered by priority:

```
let fields = ['name', 'surname', 'title']
```

and then compute the result like this:

```
let result = fields.flatMap(f => array.filter(x => x[f] === search))
```